# Retrieving a Shareable URL for a Google Drive Document Using Google Picker API

Tags: php, json, api, google-drive-api, drive

I am attempting to use the Google Drive Picker API in my site, allowing for users to select a Google Drive document. I have the picker window working entirely and it returns an object containing all metadata pertaining to the document selected. However, what I need is the shareable link from the document allowing for other, non google users, to access and view the document. None of the returned URL's meet my requirements. Is there a different API I should be using?

HTML:
    Pick File

```
<script src="filepicker.js"></script>
<script>
    function initPicker() {
        var picker = new FilePicker({
            apiKey: 'APIKEYHERE',
            clientId: 'CLIENTIDHERE',
            buttonEl: document.getElementById('pick'),
            onSelect: function(file) {
                console.log(file);
                alert('Selected ' + file.title);
                console.log("https://docs.google.com/document/d/" + file.id);
            }
        }); 
    }
</script>

<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=APIKEYHERE"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=initPicker"></script>
```

Filepicker.js:

```
/**!
 * Google Drive File Picker Example
 * By Daniel Lo Nigro (http://dan.cx/)
 */
(function() {
/**
 * Initialise a Google Driver file picker
 */
var FilePicker = window.FilePicker = function(options) {
    // Config
    this.apiKey = options.apiKey;
    this.clientId = options.clientId;
    // Elements
    this.buttonEl = options.buttonEl;   
    // Events
    this.onSelect = options.onSelect;
    this.buttonEl.addEventListener('click', this.open.bind(this));      
    // Disable the button until the API loads, as it won't work properly until then.
    this.buttonEl.disabled = true;
    // Load the drive API
    gapi.client.setApiKey(this.apiKey);
    gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', this._driveApiLoaded.bind(this));
    google.load('picker', '1', { callback: this._pickerApiLoaded.bind(this) });
}
FilePicker.prototype = {
    /**
     * Open the file picker.
     */
    open: function() {      
        // Check if the user has already authenticated
        var token = gapi.auth.getToken();
        if (token) {
            this._showPicker();
        } else {
            // The user has not yet authenticated with Google
            // We need to do the authentication before displaying the Drive picker.
            this._doAuth(false, function() { this._showPicker(); }.bind(this));
        }
    },
    /**
     * Show the file picker once authentication has been done.
     * @private
     */
    _showPicker: function() {
        var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
        this.picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
            addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCUMENTS).
            setAppId(this.clientId).
            setOAuthToken(accessToken).
            setCallback(this._pickerCallback.bind(this)).
            build().
            setVisible(true);
    },
    /**
     * Called when a file has been selected in the Google Drive file picker.
     * @private
     */
    _pickerCallback: function(data) {
        if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
            var file = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0],
                id = file[google.picker.Document.ID],
                request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
                    fileId: id
                }); 
            request.execute(this._fileGetCallback.bind(this));
        }
    },
    /**
     * Called when file details have been retrieved from Google Drive.
     * @private
     */
    _fileGetCallback: function(file) {
        if (this.onSelect) {
            this.onSelect(file);
        }
    },
    /**
     * Called when the Google Drive file picker API has finished loading.
     * @private
     */
    _pickerApiLoaded: function() {
        this.buttonEl.disabled = false;
    },
    /**
     * Called when the Google Drive API has finished loading.
     * @private
     */
    _driveApiLoaded: function() {
        this._doAuth(true);
    },
    /**
     * Authenticate with Google Drive via the Google JavaScript API.
     * @private
     */
    _doAuth: function(immediate, callback) {    
        gapi.auth.authorize({
            client_id: this.clientId + '.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly',
            immediate: immediate
        }, callback);
    }
};
}());
```